# After reboot Centos7 server , when run kubectl get pod get error: the connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused

Tags: kubernetes, centos, centos7

What happened:
when I reboot the centos7 server and run get pod, see below error:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port? What you expected to happen:

before I reboot the system, the Kubernetes have three nodes, and pods/service/,.. all working fine.
How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):

- reboot the server
- kubectl get pod

Anything else we need to know?

I even used **`sudo kubeadm reset`** and `init` again but the issue still exists!

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/88205

Comment: can you provide more details about environment? How may master nodes ? How may worker nodes? Did you reboot the master or worker?

Comment: kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.3", GitCommit:"06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T18:14:22Z", GoVersion:
"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: one master node and two work node, instances running in GCP and centos7. Before reboot all works fine, but after reboot master node , kubenetes can not work

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider:

1. [kubeadm reset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/) performs a best effort revert of changes made by kubeadm init or kubeadm join. So some configurations may stay on the cluster.
2. Make sure you run `kubectl` as a proper user. You might need to copy the `admin.conf` to `.kube/config` dir of the user's home directory.
3. After `kubeadm init` you need to run the following commands:

`sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf`

Make sure you do so.

4. Check Centos' firewall configuration. After the restart it might go back to defaults.

Please let me know if that helped.